# How to test a web service / API?

Tags: rest, testing, web-api

Our product is a C++ server component implementing a REST API. We have automatic tests that check whether the responses are byte-identical to the reference. The new requirement that came in is that the server now has to run on a different OS (built with a different compiler and standard library) too.

In trying to get our tests up and running on the new platform, we've found that the output is not byte-identical but still correct, for example floating-point results of calculations differ a bit, or a different implementation of some unordered container results in a different order of a list in the JSON response.

I'm not really familiar with all the software testing methods out there. What would be a "more correct" way of designing tests for this API?

Comment: Might be worth editing the question to say whether you are using any off the shelf testing framework / library, and if so which one(s).

Comment: Have you considered checking only the format and the contract? For example, given the request REQ, the validations ensure that the response RES to REQ ends in HTTP Status X, the response body is not empty, the response body is a well-formatted JSON, the JSON path $.x.y.z exists, the JSON path $.x.y.z is an array and it's not empty, etc. At this point in the testing, values are not that important. the correctness of the data can be guaranteed by unit tests or integration tests in different stages of the testing, not in this one (E2E)

Comment: If they're integration tests can they run on a different machine? I've been looking at using our existing postman scripts as integration tests using their open source runner called newman, maybe you could use that also

Answer (score 4):

> In trying to get our tests up and running on the new platform, we've found that the output is not byte-identical but still correct, for example floating-point results of calculations differ a bit, or a different implementation of some unordered container results in a different order of a list in the JSON response.

Yup - these are *classic* problems that show up when you are trying to use a "record and playback" style of tests to measure your system.  In effect, your test harness is "overfit" to one specific implementation, and doesn't extend very well.

> I'm not really familiar with all the software testing methods out there. What would be a "more correct" way of designing tests for this API?

There are two common approaches here.

One approach is to build a new "book" of expected responses, which are to be produced by the new system.  A straight forward way to do this would be to have a single run where you get all of the outputs from the new system, and then you have some human being compare the old and new results, and any new results blessed by the human reviewer becomes the new baseline for testing in that system.

If you have more investment up front, then you add a little bit of automation to the mix.  The old behavior acts as an *input* to a specification factory, and the specification produced by the factory is used to evaluate the new behavior.

For instance, in your list, it might be "good enough" to check that the new list is the same length as the old list, and that each element in the old list appears once in the new list.

In other words, you write code to compare the *meaning* of the response instead of comparing the *bytes*.

That said, since you apparently own the implementation of the server itself, a better investment might be to isolate and test the components of the server in isolation, rather than trying to run end to end tests.

It might be useful to review what James Bach, Michael Bolton et al have to say about [checking vs testing](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/856).  TL;DR: automated mistake detection is primarily a checking activity, and we normally want to arrange our processes so that we can detect each mistake using the most cost effective technique available.

Comment: "build a new "book" of expected responses": I think you mean if the new system was to replace the old. This is not the case: we now have to ship it for multiple platforms. (Or maybe you are sugggesting we should use a whole another set of reference outputs when testing the other platform?)

Answer (score 2):

Write your test code to decode the JSON response and test just aspects of it that matter. You may need to pull out certain values to assert on separately, e.g. floating-point results can be asserted to be approximately equal to an expected value, within an allowable maximum delta.

I'm not familiar with C++ testing, but if you use an off the shelf testing framework it may have built in support for things like this. For instance in PHP using PHPUnit, there are [`assertJsonStringEqualsJsonString`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.3/assertions.html#assertjsonstringequalsjsonstring) and [`assertEqualsWithDelata`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.3/assertions.html#assertequalswithdelta) functions.